# Trouble restoring Mvc CodeAnalysis dependencies using dotnet cli

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm having an error restoring dependencies for an ASP.NET 5/ASP.NET Core 1.0.

It appears that a couple of the dependencies (namely `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` / `.Common`) of `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` are fixed to seemingly out of date packages.

A requirement for this is to use the `dotnet` cli tool and target both .NET Vanilla and .NET Core.

**Is there any way to get Mvc to reference Core-compatible version of CodeAnalysis?**

---

Steps to reproduce in Visual Studio 2015 (v14.0.24729.00 Update 1):

1. File > New > Project > Web > ASP.NET Web Application
2. API.NET 5 Templates > Web API
3. Open PM, run command `dotnet restore`

Output:

```
info : Restoring packages for C:\PATH_TO_SOLUTION\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2\project.json...
error: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
error: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
error: Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
error: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x64).
error: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x64).
... (loads more errors) ...
```

`project.json` file contains:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    ...
  }
  ...
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the (currently) latest stable version works with as target framework only dnxcore50. In my project.json:

```
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp": "1.1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where are you putting this in your *project.json*? If I put it in `"dependencies"` then I just get resolve errors for both frameworks.

Comment: In my dependencies indeed. Are all of your nuget feeds available? Your output should log if there is one that isn't available.

Comment: Strangely it doesn't give that error, just complains they it is "Unable to resolve". However, I tried running the commmand `dotnet restore -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` and the referenced packages are installed. Running `dotnet build` then works as expected!

Comment: Interesting. You're not running v2 by accident in your package sources?

Comment: Nope! It's v3 in my roaming nuget.config.

Comment: Im getting this error trying to dotnet restore with RC2 and this solution doesnt seem to fix that - now I get `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.1 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0`

Answer (score 2):

Just installing the latest version of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` from **NuGet Package Manager** worked fine for me.